# Can a ionic app fetch data to a website's database?

Tags: ionic-framework

i was planning to make a project out of my curiosity , to make a ionic framework mobile app  that fetches data from a website's database (which i already made). Is it possible? How? i have no idea how to do that because im still on the learning process(novice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web service is a service offered by an electronic device to another electronic device, communicating with each other via the World Wide Web. In a Web service, Web technology such as HTTP, originally designed for human-to-machine communication, is utilized for machine-to-machine communication, more specifically for transferring machine readable file formats such as XML and JSON

[Using PHP and MySQL with Ionic](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic/)http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic/

[Creating an Ionic App with MySQL and Backand](http://blog.ionic.io/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this and its possible. First of all you need to create a connection that you Ionic App can communicate with your Website.

That is Called an API. If we dont use any big tech Words to explain this. 
The Common practice is build a REST-API first.

Its a Link, and when you goto the link, the link will give you data in a Format JSON or XML. So your App can Parse the JSON/XML Data and display in your Ionic App.

Example.

www.yourwebsite.com/getusers
www.yourwebsite.com/adduser

you will call the first link from your App in **GET** protocol and this will give u a list of users in JSON Format.

you will call the second link from your App in **POST** protocol with User Parameters and this will add a user and Will give you Success or Error Json/XML Response.

So first you need to learn a bit about REST-API and how to build them. You can build them in any language.

[REST API FOR BEGINNERS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA)

Then plan which language is the best for you and follow up a good tutorial.

And Finally follow this on how to call an API from IONIC 
[CALL API FROM IONIC](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api)

Cheers XD

Comment: wow so overwhelming sir i am eternally grateful for the information you have given me. As a Beginner this is more information than i could ever ask for thank you so much sir